# DOM Dropdown list with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am not a senior jQuery developer so I'm asking this on StackOverflow.

I have a dropdown list for payments (bitcoin, PayPal). The user can select one option: bitcoin or PayPal.

If the user selects `bitcoin`, placeholder of input element will change to `bitcoin address`  and `bitcoin value` will be `disabled`.

If the user selects PayPal, placeholder of input element will change and Paypal value will be enabled

There is something that I forgot in jQuery. But I don't know:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').click(function() {
        var payment = $("#example").val();
        $("#textarea").attr('placeholder', payment+' Address');

        if(("#example").val() == 'Bitcoin') {
            $("#textare").attr('placeholder','bitcoin');
        }
        if(("#example").val() == 'Paypal'); {
            $('#textare').attr('placeholder','paypal');
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.ciao { background-color: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="example">
    <option value="Paypal">Paypal</option>
    <option value="Bitcoin">Bitcoin</option>
</select>
<input type="text" class="form-name"  placeholder="Name">
<input type="text" class="form-email" placeholder="E-mail">
<input type="text" class="" id="textarea">
<input type="text" class="form-" id="textare" placeholder="Your Ammont">
```

Comment: change `if(("#example").val() = 'Bitcoin'); {` to `if(("#example").val() = 'Bitcoin') {`

Comment: And also `=` to `==` or `===` on the same line as well as below for the Paypal check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had problem with

```
if(("#example").val() = 'Bitcoin'); {
```

Syntax for `if` statement is

```
if(true) { /*do something*/ }
```

Also when you use `if` for comparing some variables, syntax should be `==` and not `=`. `==` is a Comparison Operator and `=` means equal to. Below is working example:

```js
var example = $('#example');
var textarea = $("#textarea");
var textare = $("#textare");

$(document).ready(function() {
  example.on('click', function() {
    var payment = example.val();
    textarea.attr('placeholder', payment+' Address');
  
    if( example.val() == 'Bitcoin' ) {
      textare.attr('placeholder','bitcoin');
      textare.attr('disabled', 'true');
    }
  
    if( example.val() == 'Paypal') {
      textare.attr('placeholder','paypal');           
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.ciao {
  background-color: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="example">
  <option value="Paypal">Paypal</option>                   <option value="Bitcoin">Bitcoin</option>
</select>
<input type="text" class="form-name"  placeholder="Name">
<input type="text" class="form-email" placeholder="E-mail">
<input type="text" class="" id="textarea">
<input type="text" class="form-" id="textare" placeholder="Your Ammont">
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add $ in front of `if(("#example").val() == 'Bitcoin') {` .

so it should be `if($("#example").val() == 'Bitcoin') {`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').click(function() {
        var payment = $("#example").val();
        $("#textarea").attr('placeholder', payment+' Address');

        if($("#example").val() == 'Bitcoin') {
            $("#textare").attr('placeholder','bitcoin');
        }
        if($("#example").val() == 'Paypal'); {
            $('#textare').attr('placeholder','paypal');
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.ciao { background-color: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="example">
    <option value="Paypal">Paypal</option>
    <option value="Bitcoin">Bitcoin</option>
</select>
<input type="text" class="form-name"  placeholder="Name">
<input type="text" class="form-email" placeholder="E-mail">
<input type="text" class="" id="textarea">
<input type="text" class="form-" id="textare" placeholder="Your Ammont">
```